# Help me figure out the profile likehihood given this covariance function

Tags: self-study, spatial, profile-likelihood

I'm taking a spatial stats class, and I'm on the road so I can't ask the prof for help.  Would appreciate help understanding what is going on here.

The problem is set up with $Y = X_s'\beta + e$ (with $s$ indexing coordinates).  $e$ is assumed to be second-order stationary, with the variogram

$$
\gamma(h) = \left\{\begin{array}{l r}
0 & h=0\\
\tau^2 + \sigma^2\left(\frac{3h}{2\rho}-\frac{h^3}{2\rho^3}\right) & 0 < h \leq \rho\\ 
\tau^2 + \sigma^2 & h > \rho\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $h$ is distance between two points.  For second-order stationary processes, apparently it is true that $C(h) = lim_{h' \rightarrow \infty} \gamma(h') - \gamma(h)$, where $C(h)$ is a covariance function, which is only a function of distance, because the processes is second-order stationary.  This means that the covariance function is

$$
C(h) = \left\{\begin{array}{l r}
\tau^2 + \sigma^2 & h=0\\
\sigma^2\left(1-\left(\frac{3h}{2\rho}-\frac{h^3}{2\rho^3}\right)\right) & 0 < h \leq \rho\\ 
0 & h > \rho\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
which makes intuitive sense.

Now for the trickier part (for me anyway): we are told to assume that $e$ is a gaussian process.  We are asked if we might calculate a profile likelihood as a function only of $\rho$.

The likelihood function is that of a standard multivariate normal.

My question:  how do I go about the algebra to (either) find a profile likelihood that is only a function of $\rho$, or perhaps a function of $\rho$ and $\tau$?  If the latter, how do I deal with the fact that the parameter $\tau$ will show up on the diagonals of the covariance matrix, but not on the off diagonals?  It seems like it makes the algebra intractable.

Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So, the answer to my own question occurred to me after sleeping on it, as it often does.  The covariance function up there in the question is equivalent to 
$$C(h) = \tau^2I + \sigma^2\left(1-\left(\frac{3h}{2\rho}-\frac{h^3}{2\rho^3}\right)\right)$$

which can be tractably profiled into a bivariate likelihood function.

For posterity.